# Symfony3 form builder form field in span instead of div

Tags: php, symfony, formbuilder

I have Symfony3 app and I am making a simple form the code in the twig is as follows

```
 {{ form_start(edit_form) }}
      {{ form_widget(edit_form) }}
      <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
 {{ form_end(edit_form) }}
```

Pretty simple. What this code creates is a form and each form field is within it's own `<div>` which is fine, but if the type is date here is what the generated html looks like

```
<div>
  <label class="required">Term</label>
    <div id="appbundle_project_term">
      <select id="appbundle_project_term_year" name="appbundle_project[term][year]"></select>
      <select id="appbundle_project_term_year" name="appbundle_project[term][month]"></select>
      <select id="appbundle_project_term_year" name="appbundle_project[term][day]"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

What bugs me is the inner `div` created for the date type field. Is there a way in the FormBuilder to keep the type date but remove this inner div without using javascript to handle it or in the twig template. Simply to say - "inner tag => span".
This is pretty generic question as I am looking for a way to usually change the auto generated tags, but if needed here is how this form field is created in form builder

```
add('term',DateType::class, array(
            'widget' => 'choice',
            'label'=>"Term",
            'data'=>$project->getTerm()
        ))
```

Comment: Take a look here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override form rendering, there are few ways.

The simplest one is overriding form theme widget block (in this case `date_widget`) and setting `form_theme` to `_self`.

Basic example:

```
{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block date_widget %}
    <span>
        {% if widget == 'single_text' %}
            {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
        {% else %}
            {# rendering 3 fields for year, month and day #}
            {{ form_widget(form.year) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.month) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.day) }}
        {% endif %}
    </span>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {# ... form rendering #}

    {{ form_row(form.someDateField) }}
{% endblock %}
```